# MySQL - selecting the count of an id where one count is greater than another count

Tags: mysql

Pretty new to sql statements here so this one is a bit tricky for me.

I have two tables: sold and product. Sold(SID, UPC, Date) Product(UPC, Name, Brand)

I need to find in how many stores(sid) does one brand outsell another brand.

I was thinking it was something like:

```
select count(*) from sold natural join product 
where count(brand = 'sony') > count(brand = 'samsung');
```

Clearly that isn't valid however...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
   SELECT SID
   FROM Sold
   JOIN product
   ON product.UPC = Sold.UPC -- otherwise we have a cartesian product
   GROUP BY SID -- if we need totals _by store_, we need to group on that.
   HAVING SUM(brand='sony') > SUM(brand='samsung')
) Totals.
```